Expo Error: Not a valid base64 encoded string length, js engine: hermes
I upgraded Expo from 48 to 51 and fixed all the conflict dependencies.
Ran the expo upgrade command and fix command which fixed all the dependencies on its own.
Ran the npx expo-doctor command and fixed all the warning it gave as well.
My guess is that something related to navigation is not working as expected.
Now im facing this error.
Android Bundled 25024ms index.js (1951 modules)
  ERROR  Error: Not a valid base64 encoded string length, js engine: hermes
 ERROR  Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:
* Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
* A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called., js engine: hermes


const Navigator = ({ linking, notificationChange }) => { 

  return (
    <NavigationContainer
      linking={linking}
      notificationChange={notificationChange}
    >
      <AppContext.Provider value={notificationChange}>
        <DrawerNavigator notificationChange={notificationChange} />
      </AppContext.Provider>
    </NavigationContainer>
  )
}

The error goes away and Login screen shows up, if I comment out the stacks (TabNavigator) that I'm injecting to Tabs.

import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack'

const Stack = createStackNavigator()

const DrawerManager = ({ }) => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator
      initialRouteName="HomeNav"
      screenOptions={{
        headerShown: false,
      }}
    >
      <Stack.Screen name="HomeNav" component={TabNavigator} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={Login} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Logout" component={Logout} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  )
}

export default DrawerManager

import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs'
const TabNavigator = ({ navigation }) => {
   
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
      screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
        // eslint-disable-next-line react/prop-types
        tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => {
          switch (route.name) {
            case 'Vote':
              return (
                <FontAwesome5
                  name="vote-yea"
                  size={20}
                  color={focused ? colors.primaryLight : colors.gray}
                />
              )
            case 'Analytics':
              return (
                <FontIcon
                  name="chart-bar"
                  color={focused ? colors.primaryLight : colors.gray}
                  size={20}
                  solid
                />
              )
            case 'Home':
              return (
                <FontIcon
                  name="home"
                  color={focused ? colors.primaryLight : colors.gray}
                  size={20}
                  solid
                />
              )
            case 'Request':
              return (
                <AntDesign
                  name="retweet"
                  color={focused ? colors.primaryLight : colors.gray}
                  size={20}
                  solid
                />
              )
            case 'Settings':
              return (
                <FontIcon
                  name="cog"
                  color={focused ? colors.primaryLight : colors.gray}
                  size={20}
                  solid
                />
              )
            default:
              return <View />
          }
        },
        tabBarVisible: shouldTabBarBeVisible(route),
      })}
      tabBarOptions={{
        activeTintColor: colors.primaryLight,
        inactiveTintColor: colors.gray,
        keyboardHidesTabBar: true,
        style: {
          // backgroundColor: 'white',
          // borderTopColor: 'gray',
          // borderTopWidth: 1,
          // paddingBottom: 5,
          // paddingTop: 5,
        },
      }}
      initialRouteName="Home"
      swipeEnabled={false}
    >
      <Tab.Screen name="Vote" component={VoteNavigator} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Analytics" component={GraphNavigator} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeNavigator} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Request" component={RequestNavigator} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Settings" component={AppConfigNavigator} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  )
}

import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack'
const Stack = createStackNavigator()
export const VoteNavigator = () => (
  <Stack.Navigator
    initialRouteName="Home"
    headerMode="screen"
    screenOptions={navigationProps}
  >
    <Stack.Screen
      name="Vote"
      component={Vote}
      options={({ navigation }) => ({
        title: 'Vote',
      })}
    />
    <Stack.Screen
      name="votingpage"
      component={Votingpage}
      options={({ navigation }) => ({
        title: 'select point',
      })}
    />
    <Stack.Screen
      name="attributelist"
      component={ModifiedList}
      options={({ navigation }) => ({
        title: 'Select attribute',
      })}
    />

    <Stack.Screen
      name="userlist"
      component={Userlist}
      options={({ navigation }) => ({
        title: 'Vote',
      })}
    />

    {/* <Stack.Screen
      name="gifpicker"
      component={Gifs}
      options={({ navigation, route }) => ({
        title: 'Select a GIF',
        headerRight: () => <SkipButton navigation={navigation} route={route} />,
      })}
    /> */}
  </Stack.Navigator>
)

packege.json
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start --dev-client",
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.23.1",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
    "@react-native-community/toolbar-android": "0.1.0-rc.1",
    "@react-native/assets-registry": "^0.74.85",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.6.1",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.7.2",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.18",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.4.1",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.5.1",
    "@types/parse": "^2.18.13",
    "@types/react": "18.2.79",
    "biglist-with-tabs": "^1.0.1",
    "deepmerge": "^4.2.2",
    "esm": "^3.2.25",
    "expo": "51",
    "expo-asset": "~10.0.10",
    "expo-build-properties": "~0.12.3",
    "expo-camera": "~15.0.14",
    "expo-constants": "~16.0.2",
    "expo-dev-client": "~4.0.20",
    "expo-device": "~6.0.2",
    "expo-file-system": "~17.0.1",
    "expo-font": "~12.0.9",
    "expo-image-manipulator": "~12.0.5",
    "expo-intent-launcher": "~11.0.1",
    "expo-linking": "~6.3.1",
    "expo-location": "~17.0.1",
    "expo-media-library": "~16.0.4",
    "expo-notifications": "~0.28.10",
    "expo-screen-orientation": "~7.0.5",
    "expo-sensors": "~13.0.9",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.27.5",
    "expo-sqlite": "~14.0.4",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.12.1",
    "expo-system-ui": "~3.0.7",
    "expo-updates": "~0.25.20",
    "fast-fuzzy": "^1.11.1",
    "global": "^4.4.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "parse": "3.4.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.74.3",
    "react-native-collapsible-with-infinite-scroll": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-dropdown-picker": "^5.4.4",
    "react-native-flash-message": "^0.2.1",
    "react-native-fs": "^2.20.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.16.1",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.5",
    "react-native-orientation-locker": "^1.6.0",
    "react-native-pager-view": "6.3.0",
    "react-native-paper": "^4.12.5",
    "react-native-plotly": "^6.0.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~3.10.1",
    "react-native-responsive-screen": "^1.4.2",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.10.5",
    "react-native-screens": "3.31.1",
    "react-native-status-bar-height": "^2.6.0",
    "react-native-svg": "15.2.0",
    "react-native-svg-transformer": "^0.14.3",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^3.1.1",
    "react-native-table-component": "^1.2.2",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.19.10",
    "react-native-webview": "13.8.6",
    "react-redux": "^9.1.2",
    "redux": "4.0.5",
    "redux-persist": "6.0.0",
    "redux-thunk": "2.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.19.3",
    "@babel/node": "^7.16.8",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.16.11",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.16.7",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^4.0.0",
    "babel-preset-expo": "~11.0.0",
    "braces": ">=2.3.1",
    "react-devtools": "^4.22.0"
  },
  "name": "hexmos.karma",
  "version": "1.0.0"
}


babel.config.js
module.exports = (api) => {
  presets: [
    ['@babel/preset-env', { targets: { node: 'current' } }],
    '@babel/preset-typescript',
  ],
    api.cache(true)
  return {
    presets: ['babel-preset-expo'],
    plugins: [
      [
        'module-resolver',
        {
          alias: {
            components: './src/components',
            pages: './src/pages',
            theme: './src/theme',
            utils: './src/utils',
            slices: './src/slices',
          },
        },
      ],
      'react-native-reanimated/plugin',
    ],
  }
}

index.js
import { registerRootComponent } from 'expo';

import App from './App';

// registerRootComponent calls AppRegistry.registerComponent('main', () => App);
// It also ensures that whether you load the app in Expo Go or in a native build,
// the environment is set up appropriately
registerRootComponent(App);

app.json
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "Feedback by Hexmos",
    "slug": "hexmoskarma",
    "version": "1.0.234",
    "orientation": "default",
    "icon": "./src/assets/AdaptiveIcon.png",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./src/assets/squareFeedbackLogo.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF"
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": ["**/*"],
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0,
      "url": "http://localhost:3000/api/manifest"
    },
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "extra": {
      "eas": {
        "projectId": "d567eb36-d05b-4429-91fc-9b8d02d229d8"
      }
    },
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": false,
      "bundleIdentifier": "com.hexmos.karma"
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./src/assets/AdaptiveIcon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF"
      },
      "package": "com.hexmos.karma",
      "versionCode": 234,
      "googleServicesFile": "./google-services.json"
    },
    "plugins": [
      [
        "expo-location",
        {
          "locationAlwaysAndWhenInUsePermission": "Allow Feedback to use your location."
        }
      ],
      "./plugins/withAndroidNamespace",
      "./plugins/withAndroidExpoFix",
      [
        "expo-updates",
        {
          "username": "hexmos"
        }
      ]
    ],
    "scheme": "hexmoskarma"
  }
}

App.js
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react'
import { View } from 'react-native'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { store, persistor } from 'utils/store'
import 'utils/ignore'
// assets
import { loadImageAssets } from 'theme/images'
import { loadFontAssets } from 'theme/fonts'
import Navigator from './navigator'
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/integration/react'
import { initParse } from './utils/parsehandler'
import { Provider as PaperProvider } from 'react-native-paper'
import * as Linking from 'expo-linking'
import * as Notifications from 'expo-notifications'
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage'
import SnackbarComp from './components/SnackbarComp'

const prefix = Linking.createURL('/')
console.log('Prefix is: ', prefix)
console.log('App.js')
// Supports opening deep links of the sort:
// npx uri-scheme open exp://192.168.0.101:19000/--/onboard/email/sampleu0@email.com/otp/12345/org/Hexmos --android
const config = {
  screens: {
    Login: 'login',
    Logout: 'logout',
    Onboard: {
      screens: {
        OnboardComp: {
          path: 'onboard/email/:email/otp/:otp/org/:org/omid/:omid',
          parse: {
            org: (org) => decodeURIComponent(org),
            email: (email) => decodeURIComponent(email),
            otp: (otp) => decodeURIComponent(otp),
            omid: (omid) => decodeURIComponent(omid),
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
}

const linking = {
  prefixes: ['https://icdroid.com', prefix],
  config,
}

Linking.addEventListener('url', ({ url }) => {
  console.log('Received a URL: ' + url)
})

Notifications.setNotificationHandler({
  handleNotification: async () => ({
    shouldShowAlert: true,
    shouldPlaySound: true,
    shouldSetBadge: true,
  }),
})

const App = () => {
  const [didLoad, setDidLoad] = useState(false)
  const [notificationChange, setNotificationChange] = useState(0)
  const notificationListener = useRef()
  const responseListener = useRef()

  const lastNotificationResponse = Notifications.useLastNotificationResponse()
  const getAllNotificationResponse =
    Notifications.getPresentedNotificationsAsync()

  React.useEffect(() => {
    ; (async () => {
      if (lastNotificationResponse) {
        await storeNavigation(
          lastNotificationResponse.notification.request.content.data,
        )
        setNotificationChange(Math.random())
      }
    })()
  }, [lastNotificationResponse])

  React.useEffect(() => {
    ; (async () => {
      const nonInteractedNotifications = await getAllNotificationResponse
      if (
        nonInteractedNotifications !== undefined &&
        nonInteractedNotifications !== null
      ) {
        nonInteractedNotifications.forEach(async (el) => {
          if (el.request.content.data.data === 'karma-force-logout') {
            console.log('GN - 1', el.request.identifier)
            await Notifications.dismissNotificationAsync(el.request.identifier)
            await storeNavigation(el.request.content.data)
          }
        })
      }
    })()
  }, [])

  async function storeNavigation(notificationKey) {
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('navigate', notificationKey.data)
    if (notificationKey.data === 'karma-push-notification-request-for-vote') {
      await AsyncStorage.setItem('rfvUserId', notificationKey.request_user_id)
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    notificationListener.current =
      Notifications.addNotificationReceivedListener((notification) => {
        if (notification.request.content.data.data === 'karma-force-logout') {
          console.log('Log me out - Navigate')
        }
      })

    responseListener.current =
      Notifications.addNotificationResponseReceivedListener(
        async (response) => {
          console.log('addNotificationResponseReceivedListener')
          // await storeNavigation()
          // setNotificationChange(Math.random())
        },
      )

    return () => {
      Notifications.removeNotificationSubscription(notificationListener.current)
      Notifications.removeNotificationSubscription(responseListener.current)
    }
  }, [])

  // assets preloading
  const handleLoadAssets = async () => {
    await Promise.all([...loadImageAssets, ...loadFontAssets])
    initParse()
    setDidLoad(true)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    handleLoadAssets()
  }, [])

  return didLoad ? (
    <PaperProvider>
      <Provider store={store}>
        <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
          <Navigator
            linking={linking}
            notificationChange={notificationChange}
          />
          <SnackbarComp />
        </PersistGate>
      </Provider>
    </PaperProvider>
  ) : (
    <View />
  )
}

export default App

lovestaco@i3nux-mint:~/repos/icdroid$ npx expo-doctor
(node:9183) [DEP0040] DeprecationWarning: The `punycode` module is deprecated. Please use a userland alternative instead.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
✔ Check Expo config for common issues
✔ Check package.json for common issues
✔ Check native tooling versions
✔ Check dependencies for packages that should not be installed directly
✔ Check for common project setup issues
✔ Check for issues with metro config
✔ Check npm/ yarn versions
✔ Check Expo config (app.json/ app.config.js) schema
✔ Check that packages match versions required by installed Expo SDK
✔ Check that native modules do not use incompatible support packages
✔ Check for legacy global CLI installed locally
✔ Check that native modules use compatible support package versions for installed Expo SDK

Didn't find any issues with the project!

Not able to understand whats the error even about
